# Merge tags 'numeric' 'numerical' 'numerical-methods' and 'numerical-analysis'

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

I went to add a tag favorite for something related to numerical computing, and found that there are several distinct tags that all fit this area. Their tag wiki descriptions are almost identical, and the contents carry no particular distinction, but they're separate:

- [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric)
- [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis)
- [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical)
- [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods)

I haven't previously contributed enough in these tags to be allowed to suggest a synonym, so I'm posting here instead.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be useful if you suggest the main tag and explain slightly more why the merge should be done. [tag:numeric] and [tag:numerical] have identical wikis (and clearly should be merged), but [tag:numerical-analysis] and [tag:numerical-methods] aren't as clear-cut.

Answer (score 2):

I proposed to make [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) a synonym for [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods). If the suggestion is accepted, then all questions tagged "numerical analysis" will become tagged with "numerical methods" instead. The latter has many more questions and a complete Wiki, the former doesn't. I think "numerical methods" incorporates the concept of analyzing those methods, so this synonym direction makes sense to me.

You can vote for this proposal here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical-methods/synonyms

[numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) and [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical) are already synonyms.

Someone apparently proposed a synonym that would make [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) a synonym of [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric). I cannot see this proposal, apparently I don't have 5 points in the numeric tag. But it prevents me from proposing the reverse, which I would prefer.