# Merge the [numeric] and [numerical] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

#### Please merge [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) and [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical).

Here is the tag description for [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric):

> This tag is for questions concerning problems using numbers which either cannot be exactly solved, or where the exact solution may be much more difficult to acquire than by using numerical methods.

Here is the tag description for [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical):

> This tag is for questions concerning problems using numbers which either cannot be exactly solved, or where the exact solution may be much more difficult to acquire than by using numerical methods.

Why do we have these tags differentiated? They should be synonyms.

Comment: Actually, why not burn both? They seem fairly meta to me.

Comment: A [numerical-methods] tag would *certainly* not be meta, @Tunaki. Judging by the tag wiki excerpts, that is the purpose of these tags. It may be that many of the questions are improperly tagged, but that doesn't make the tag bad.

Comment: @CodyGray we've agreed that if a tag is being misused because *reasons*, any effort to stop this misuse is welcomed.

Comment: "Numeric" also seems to be used for "I'm writing numbers in my code and I want to make sure I'm getting the types right."  And "My language has a type called 'numeric'; please clue me in."

Comment: what about "numbers"?

Comment: Does that have the same description?

Comment: Does [tag:numerics] need to go at the same time?

Comment: "where the exact solution may be much more difficult to acquire than by using numerical methods" This part of the description somehow sounds totally wrong.

Comment: @alexwlchan Actually, numerics could be the non meta tag everyone is looking for here. Numerics as in "numerical computing, i.e. programms that solve numerical problems".

Comment: Has been brought up before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295107/merge-tags-numeric-numerical-numerical-methods-and-numerical-analysis?rq=1 (suggestion from the "Related" section)

Comment: I was just about to make the same question, any news? The situation is still that bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interesting fact about the two tags are that not just their tag excerpts, but the tag wikis of both of them are the same as well.

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numeric/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical/info (see [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9845756/revisions))

This is highly indicative that they're the same tag and should be made synonyms. They're now synonymized. [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical) had 539 questions when it was remapped.

I synonymized [numerics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerics) as well, which didn't have any tag wiki, and was a pluralization of the [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric) tag.