# The [numerical-analysis] and [numerical-methods] tags are within machine epsilon of each other

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

These two tags are very similar. I think they should be merged.

- Beginning of the description of [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods):

  > Numerical methods include the study of algorithms that use numerical approximation (as opposed to general symbolic manipulations) for the problems of mathematical analysis (as distinguished from discrete mathematics) [...]
- Full description of [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis):

  > Numerical analysis is the study of algorithms that use numerical approximation, as opposed to general symbolic manipulations.

So [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) clearly includes [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis), and has a longer, clearer description (not shown here in full).

In addition, [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) has 1778 tagged questions, whereas [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) has 270. There are 86 questions that have both tags.

I propose to merge the two tags, specifically remove [numerical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) and retag the questions that currently have that tag as [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods).

Comment: Just cast them from double to float to merge them

Comment: Agreed that these can be merged.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward; one should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: Related: [Merge tags 'numeric' 'numerical' 'numerical-methods' and 'numerical-analysis'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295107)

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the other question? The other one does not suggest any action (see the comment in that question)

Comment: Does not suggest any action? The title literally starts with "Merge".

Comment: @CodyGray Let me rephrase: it doesn't suggest what the "surviving" tag should be, or why; specially for `numerical-methods` and `numerical-analysis`. Please see [the comment to that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295107/merge-tags-numeric-numerical-numerical-methods-and-numerical-analysis#comment197589_295107)

Comment: So post an answer to it with your suggestions! That's how we deal with retag/synonym questions.

Comment: Please vote for the synonym here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numerical-methods/synonyms